# How to show HTML content in the Algolia search results page on Instant Search Page

Tags: php, wordpress, algolia

I have a WordPress website with Algolia and i would like to show product `short_description` (i.e. `post_excpert`) in the search results in the HTML format.

Yes i'm using woocommerce product plugin.

Attributes already indexed with the Algolia and returning in the response as well from the Algolia.

Sample Content :

```
<table class="product-tab"> <tbody> <tr> <td>ABCD Power</td> <td>20 kW </td> </tr> <tr> <td>Volatile</td> <td>Article 63A</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Working File</td> <td>750 cm</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Hard Weight</td> <td>720 kg</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Currently its showing with HTML tags but i want HTML should be applied on the attribute.

Few other notes

1. Using Instantsearch
2. Wordpress plugin named search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results (I know it's archieved) :)

**File Instantsearch.php**

```
var search = instantsearch({
                    appId: algolia.application_id,
                    apiKey: algolia.search_api_key,
                    indexName: algolia.indices.searchable_posts.name,
                    urlSync: {
                        mapping: {'q': 's'},
                        trackedParameters: ['query']
                    },
                    searchParameters: {
                        facetingAfterDistinct: true,
                        highlightPreTag: '__ais-highlight__',
                        highlightPostTag: '__/ais-highlight__'
                    }
                });

search.addWidget(
                    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
                        container: '#algolia-hits',
                        hitsPerPage: 10,
                        escapeHTML: true,
                        templates: {
                            empty: 'No results were found for "<strong>{{query}}</strong>".',
                            item: wp.template('instantsearch-hit')
                        },
                        transformData: {
                            item: function (hit) {

                                function replace_highlights_recursive (item) {                                  
                                  if( item instanceof Object && item.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
                                      item.value = _.escape(item.value);
                                      item.value = item.value.replace(/__ais-highlight__/g, '<em>').replace(/__\/ais-highlight__/g, '</em>');
                                  } else {
                                      for (var key in item) {
                                          item[key] = replace_highlights_recursive(item[key]);
                                      }
                                  }
                                  return item;
                                }

                                hit._highlightResult = replace_highlights_recursive(hit._highlightResult);
                                hit._snippetResult = replace_highlights_recursive(hit._snippetResult);

                                return hit;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                );
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-instantsearch-hit">
        <article itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <# if ( data.images.thumbnail ) { #>
            <div class="ais-hits--thumbnail">
                <a href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}">
                    <img src="{{ data.images.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ data.post_title }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}" itemprop="image" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <# } #>

            <div class="ais-hits--content">
                <h2 itemprop="name headline"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}" itemprop="url">{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}</a></h2>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    <p>
            <# if ( data._snippetResult['content'] ) { #>
              <span class="suggestion-post-content">{{{ data._snippetResult['content'].value }}}</span>
            <# } #> 
                    </p>
                    <?php /*<p> <# if ( data.post_excerpt ) { #>
                    <span class="post-short-description">{{ data.post_excerpt }} </span>
                    <# } #></p> */ ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ais-clearfix"></div>
        </article>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering the question for reference. Added braces in the following form and it works.

```
<p> <# if ( data.post_excerpt ) { #>
<span class="post-short-description">{{{ data.post_excerpt }}} </span>
<# } #></p>
```

Comment: Appreciate you coming back and answering this. Answered my question!